# Actionbar pushed by CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

The action bar is getting pushed by the CoordinatorLayout as it appears in the following image:

(The ActionBar looks missing it's upper part and if I go back to another activity it stays missing the upper part)

[image]

- What am I missing?
- Can I use CoordinatorLayout in ViewPager or it shouldn't be used in it?
- Can CoordinatorLayout be used in fragment.

  > test.xml:

  ```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/main_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

      <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
          android:id="@+id/appbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="256dp"
          android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
          android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

          <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
              android:id="@+id/CollapsingToolbar"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
              app:collapsedTitleGravity="center"
              app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Design.CollapsingToolbar.Expanded.Shadow"
              app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
              app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="50dp"
              app:expandedTitleMarginStart="50dp"
              app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Design.CollapsingToolbar.Expanded.Shadow"
              app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

              <ImageView
                  android:id="@+id/IV"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                  android:scaleType="centerInside"
                  app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

              <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                  app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                  app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

          </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

      </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


      <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@color/whiteBackground"
          app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

              <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_margin="10dp"
                  app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/grayBackground"
                  app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                  app:cardElevation="5dp">

                  <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/tv1"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_gravity="center"
                      android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                      android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                      android:textStyle="bold" />
              </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

              <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_margin="10dp"
                  app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/grayBackground"
                  app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                  app:cardElevation="5dp">

                  <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/tv2"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                      android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                      android:textSize="20sp" />
              </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
          </LinearLayout>
      </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

      <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
          android:id="@+id/FAB"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_margin="16dp"
          android:clickable="true"
          app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
          app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
          app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|start"
          app:rippleColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
          app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_more_black_24dp" />

  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
  ```

Comment: the following code is not showing in the beginning of xml file:
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem by removing `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from the `CoordinatorLayout`.